# Windows TCP/socket/thread/buffer exhaustion (c#)

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, sockets, tcp

**Foreword**:
In a VMware environment we are running a windows 2012 server. On the server we have several application running in windows processes.
One process are opening a socket (tcp server) and listen for clients. There are 3000 clients connecting and sending data to the server process.
A scenario could be that each client sends 50 messages to the server process (3000 *50 = 150000 msg to process)
A message is decrypted with a key that is requested from a shared keystore(served from another server eg. a network call)

[See diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cV5h.png)

**Problem**
The tcp server process cannot handle the messages in time because the network call to the keyrepository is “slow”. The threadcount increases as the “async receiving” buffer up threads(C# socket.ReceiveAsync()). That problem I understand. 
BUT when other threads in that process, unrelated to socket receiving, needs to make a network connection to eg. a datastore: An connection exception raises:"An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server" - this is only periodic when the tcpserver is under full load.

Can anybody explain how this is related? Or how I can troubleshoot or investigate such issue?

Comment: This is very typical failure on a server running TCP.The client has to keep a table of each packet sent so if the ACK isn't received a retry can occur.The server has to keep a table because packets can be received in any order and must hold packets until it can send to application the data in correct order.When a server is slow it can't ACK a packet in time so the client sends another packets.The sever must then process the original packet and the 2nd packet adding additional processing time slowing the server even more.  Eventually there are so many reties the server crashes.

Comment: my initial thoughts would be either ephemera port exhaustion, or thread-pool saturation leading to a timeout; 3000 clients isn't  huge, but if they all try to call in at once, then the thread-pool could be a limiting factor - it grows painfully slowly for high volume schenarios

Comment: @jdweng That shouldn't happen, because senders use exponential backoff.

Comment: Probably, you should interpret and post the full exception. The fragment that is posted probably is a small subset of the information available.

Comment: I also wonder why we are talking so much about threads if you're using async IO. Unless the server is near 100% CPU there should not be many threads around since there would not be pressure to create many. So is really all relevant IO async (as it should be with that many clients)?

Comment: immibis : I have seen the issue a lot.  Windows doesn't always switch processes.  TCP default requires an ACK within 5 seconds.  So if TCP process doesn't execute within 5 seconds 3000 retries will occur one from each client.